# Perl - best practices in dealing with invalid data passed to a sub

Tags: perl

What is best practice in Perl when data is passed incorrectly to a subroutine? Should the sub die or just return?

Here is what I usually do

```
my @text = ('line 1', 'line 2');

print_text(\@text) 
   or die "ERROR: something went wrong in the sub";

sub print_text{
   my ($aref_text) = @_;
   return unless ref($aref_text) eq "ARRAY";
   print "$_\n" for @{$aref_text};
   return 1;
}
```

Here the sub just returns if the passed input is invalid and it expects the caller to check for errors as it does here. I wonder if it is always a better practice to just "die" at the sub level. In big scripts, I'm afraid of doing that because I don't want to kill the entire script just because some simple sub fails.

On the other hand, I'm afraid of just returning because if the caller forgets to check if the sub returns true, then the script will keep going and weird stuff could happen.

Comment: That should be part of debugging, and I think it gives a false sense of security to code such specific checks. Making sure that a given parameter is really, say, an array reference covers only a very small fraction of possible errors, and Perl will raise an exception of its own if you try to dereference something else as an array. By far the most common errors are largely undetectable, for instance your reference may refer to an an array with old data.

Comment: It is rare to have code that can fail without making the whole run invalid, so it would be better to `die` with useful information than to let your program continue and just provide incorrect results. But no amount of type checking can provide the same protection as the most minimal test procedure. That is why the elaborate and verbose syntax of Java and C++ is based on a misconception. Perl is undeservedly infamous for many things, but being prone to faulty code isn't one of them even though it has only very basic type checking.

Comment: Note that the simple decision to `or` the return will make this `die` if the return is `0`, for instance.  I think that you meant this only as an example, but what if `0` (or empty string) _is_ a valid return?  Then you'd condition it on `defined`, so `func() // die ...` I suppose.  But what if returing `undef` is a good solution for an invalid result?  Etc. It's a part of a bigger design decision, which in principle should take into account all of your code. There is no "best practice."

Comment: What's really important is having unit tests that test your edge cases on bad variables so that you are confident that if a user does send in incorrect data, you know exactly what the program will do in those cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This falls squarely under the question of how to deal with errors in subroutines in general.

In principle, these are ways to handle errors in subroutines that can't themselves recover

- return codes, some of which indicate errors
- return "special" values, like `undef` in Perl
- throw exceptions, and a device for that in Perl is [die](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die) ([croak/confess](https://perldoc.perl.org/Carp) from modules)

The caller either checks the return, or tests for `undef`, or uses [`eval`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval)<sup>†</sup> to catch and handle the `die`. What is most suitable depends entirely on the context and on what the code does.

I don't see much reason in modern languages to be restrained to "codes" (like negative values) that indicate errors.  For one thing, that either interferes will legitimate returns or it constrains them to go via pointer/reference, which is a big design decision.

Returning `undef` is often a good middle-of-the-road approach, in particular in code that isn't overly complex. It indicates some "failure" of the sub to perform what it is meant to.  However, even in the smallest of subs `undef` may be suitable to indicate a *result* that isn't acceptable. Then if it is also used for bad input we have a problem of distinguishing between those failings.

Throwing an exception, based in Perl on the simple `die`, adds more possibilities. In complex code you may well want to write (or use) an error-handling class that mimics a more elaborate exception handling support from languages that have it, and then throw that

```
my $error_obj = ErrorHandlingClass->new( params );

... or die $error_obj;
```

Then the calling code can analyze the object. This would be the most structured way to do it.

A nice and simple example is [Path::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/%7Edagolden/Path-Tiny-0.104/lib/Path/Tiny.pm), with its own `Path::Tiny::Error` found in its [source](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/DAGOLDEN/Path-Tiny-0.104/lib/Path/Tiny.pm).

Again, what is suitable in any one particular case depends on details of that application.

---

A few comments on direct questions.

The dilemma of what to return is stressed by the information-free message in `die` (it tells us nothing of what failed). But how do we make the failure  informative, in this case?

Note that your `or` results in a `die` if the sub returns `0` or an empty string. If we replace it with `//` (defined-or), so to `die` on `undef`, we still can't print a specific message if `undef` may also indicate a bad result.

So in this case you may want the function to `die` on bad input, with a suitable message.

That would do it for debugging after there's been a problem. If the code needs to be able to *recover* then you'd better return more structured information -- throw (or return) an object of an error handling class you'd write. (As an ad hoc stop-gap measure you can parse the message from `die`.)

As for the age-old question of discipline to check returns, a `die` is a good tool. There is no "*simple sub*" that is unworthy – you do not want to proceed with an error so it's OK to `die`. And in complex projects error handling is more complex, so we need *more* tools and structure, not less.

Recall that exceptions "bubble up", propagate up the call stack if unhandled, and so does `die`.  This can be used nicely for debugging without having `eval` on every single call.  In the end, most of this is a part of debugging.

There is no "best practice" for this. But a default of `die`-ing is rather reasonable.

Beyond a specific choice, consistency is usually extremely helpful, and generally important.  In a new project, choose the approach carefully and stick to it as much as possible; in an existing codebase do it the way it's done elsewhere, again as much as possible.  At least within a package I'd say.

---

<sup>†</sup>  By now we seem to be getting a `try`-`catch` style handling of an exception (`die`) support in the core. It is introduced as [experimental in 5.34.0](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlexperiment#try/catch-control-structure), but they recommend using [Feature::Compat::Try](https://metacpan.org/pod/Feature::Compat::Try) for now. This is
ported from [Syntax::Keyword::Try](https://metacpan.org/pod/Syntax::Keyword::Try).

Comment: can a `die` actually be caught and handled?  can you do something like try{die 'foo';}catch($ex){} ?

Comment: @hanshenrik  Oh yes, that is what makes it the (simple-minded)
 exception handling mechanism in Perl.  It's caught with [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) (its block form).  There are modules that wrap it and provide `try`-style syntax, and then yet others that go well beyond.  But it's all based on `die`-`eval`.

Comment: @JohnnyLoo I added a section with more direct comments on your questions

Comment: The best practice is often to do what the other subroutines are already doing, even if that is wrong. I'd rather have a subroutine doing it "wrong" in the same way than several subroutines all doing it "wrong" in different ways.

Comment: @briandfoy "_The best practice is often to do what the other subroutines are already doing,..._" -- yes, that's the main thing -- a good point, which I missed to make -- added at the end of the post -- thank you.  I kinda draw a line at a package level -- if there's compelling reasons I'm ok with changing approach across libraries.

Answer (score -1):

First, someone not checking the subroutine's return value is their problem.

I try to make things simpler for the user, which is sometimes more code for me.

Although you've only given a simple example, there are cases where I've had interfaces that accepted a single, simple scalar or an array reference in the same position. Consider the case where most uses are single items (so an array ref of one item):

```
print_text( [ $foo ] );
```

And, what do I care if this fails? What would I do? Use `print_text` to note a failure? How many people check the return value of `print`? :)

This comes up a lot when I add simple logging to programs that don't want to reach for modules for robust logging. Often I have a single string I want to log:

```
debug( $foo );
```

Sometimes I might have more than one:

```
debug( $foo, $bar );
```

And maybe I get those values from something

```
my $aref = do_something();
debug( $aref );
```

I'd much rather do more work in the subroutine to do less work calling it. I might do a little massaging:

```
sub print_text{
   my @list = do {
       if( @_ > 1 ) { @_ }
       elsif( ref $_[0] ) { $_[0]->@* }
       elsif( @_ == 0 ) { '' } # or some default
       else { $_[0] }. # or other branches too
       };

   print "$_\n" for @list;
}
```

This sort of adapting interface might not make sense for your use, though. There are many places where we can help the user, as long as we are doing it in a way that makes sense for the entire codebase. For some other examples, look under the hood of Mojolicious. This sort of thing happens a lot because they aim to build user friendly interfaces.

For much more complicated things when I absolutely want to report errors, I tend to return result objects that the caller can query to see what happened. This is similar to give `die` an object, but skipping the die and exception handling. See [ReturnValue](https://metacpan.org/pod/ReturnValue) as a demonstration (it's better to make your own that's serves your own situation). Remember, with object oriented programming we know a lot from an objects type (the same thing you'd do it classify an exception, but without the exception). The OO idea has what you need already.